# In a php.ini file there is '2M' where I expect a number - what does it mean?

Tags: php

My employer needs a change to some PHP files that lead me to need to look in the 'php.ini' file which I have never done before. The line I care about is:

`upload_max_filesize = 2M`

Does '2M' mean 2 million? If not, what does it mean? I don't need to change it, I just need to know what number it represents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a PHP shorthand byte value. You can find out more from http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes

Answer (score 3):

2 megabytes. I don't know if that's 2^20 bytes or 10^6 bytes, but that doesn't really make much of a difference.

Comment: `2 * 2^20` From the [manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes): `1M equals one Megabyte or 1048576 bytes`

Answer (score 1):

2M=2*2^10 BYTES . This is the default MAX SIZE for UPLOAD defined by PHP , which can be changed to any number you like

Answer (score 1):

2M is 2 megabytes (2*1024*1024)

You can read about it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) and [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes)